# How do I avoid a 500 error with .php hiding using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got this in my .htaccess file:

```
    ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

When I try to access a page or directory that isn't there, I get 'Error 500 - internal server error'. I am using GoDaddy, if it is relevant.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? There should be relevant information regarding the actual error there.

Comment: Yes, but there are many logs and I don't know which to look at.

Comment: I cannot help you navigate your service. You should either look for GoDaddy resources explaining where to find your error logs, or ask their support for help.